# How binding executable have in-memory address of api imported from other Dll?

Tags: dll, binding, dllimport, dllexport

I'm reading about binding where i encounter this line.

`"The executable file on disk has the actual in-memory addresses of APIs in other DLLs in its IAT. When loading a bound executable."`

Dlls can't be load at same address location in memory. So Please explain me How the binding executable have in-memory Address.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It is just a preferred address and it depends on the windows service packs and versions,...
If the dll is not loaded at the preferred address or TimeDateStamp mismatches, it'll use arbitrary IAT loading.

[ALLOWBIND switch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zz94b337.aspx)

> Binding has no effect if address space layout randomization (ASLR) is enabled for the image by using /DYNAMICBASE on versions of Windows that support ASLR.